# sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long) always true?

Tags: c, types, primitive-types

From C standard, int has of at least 16bit, long has of at least 32bit and at least 64bit for long long if any (some platforms may not support). Just wondering if the sentence as title is always true.

Comment: I love how the 'yes' and the 'no' basically have the same number of votes. LOL

Comment: Yes is the practical answer, No is the theorical one.

Comment: As a matter of interest, does anyone know of an actual C implementation where what the questioner asks is not true?

Comment: The fact that the "Yes it is always true" answer has so many votes illustrates the problem in using democracy to answer technical questions. No citation, and probably not even correct, but it fits most people's (mis?)conceptions, so it gets lots of votes. It'd be nice if people would actually cite a standard when answering questions that start out "from C standard".

Comment: I think it would even be nicer if people don't vote up if they don't know whether the answer is true. You may aswell cite the Standard, but then cite the wrong portion of it. It's all the voters fault.

Answer (score 18):

No. The standard only defines the minimum ranges for each of those types. Conceivably int could have a 16-bit range, but 48 bits of padding, bringing it to 64-bits (8 bytes, if CHAR_BITS == 8), while long is 32-bits (4 bytes).

Of course, this would be silly. But it's not forbidden, as such.

Note, however, that `sizeof(char) == 1`, by definition. So `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(`*anything else*`)`.

Comment: Are you sure about sizeof(char) <= sizeof(anything else)?

Comment: Given that the unit of sizeof is sizeof(char) (it returns an integer factor of sizeof(char), by definition), I'd hope so.

Comment: While C++ requires `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` etc, I think C doesn't, and it in fact allows `sizeof(int) > sizeof(long)` etc because of padding as far as i know. But both require that `INT_MAX <= LONG_MAX` etc.

Comment: My understanding if the same as litb (C++ requires it, C lacks the formal rules requiring it even if it would be a very strange implementation not to respect that inequality)

Answer (score 7):

According to [C Programming/Reference Tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables), particularly the [Table of Data Types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables#Table_of_Data_Types):

> int ≥ 16 ≥ size of short
>
> long ≥ 32 ≥ size of int
>
> long long ≥ 64 ≥ size of long

As bdonlan pointed out, this only refers to the range of the values, not the size in memory (which sizeof returns in bytes).  The C standard doesn't specify the size in memory that each type can use, so it's left to the implementation.

Comment: Those are bits, not bytes, and thus refers to the range of the type - unless sizeof(int) really >= 16 on your machine :). Does this apply to the results of the sizeof() operator as well?

Comment: @bdonlan: Thanks, I see the distinction now.  I edited my answer to be as correct as it can be. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Practical C++ Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004192) says that

> C++ guarantees that the storage for **short** <= **int** <= **long**

Still searching for **long long**.

Comment: That's C++. The question asked about C and the C standard. They don't have to agree.

Comment: Silly me didn't notice the "C" tag for this question... sorry for the C++ reference!

Comment: And you should understamnd what any particular text book tells you may well not be true. Text books do not define a languge - international standards do.

Comment: The K&R C book was the quintessential standard for the C language before C89. Also lua, a widely used language, has no international standard and is defined by it's reference manual.

Comment: by the way, you can quit searching. long long is not part of C++ yet. :)

Comment: @Falaina Arguably so, though if you are talking about the 1st ed of K&R, definitely not. However, "Practical C++ Programming" definitely does not define C or C++.

Answer (score 2):

At least for ISO C++, this is well-defined (excepting `long long` for obvious reasons) by the Standard in 3.9.1[basic.fundamental]/2:

> There are four signed integer types: “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, and “long int.” In this list, each type provides *at least as much storage* as those preceding it in the list.

Note that this is speaking of storage, not value ranges. This specifically means `sizeof`.

Comment: What are the *obvious reasons* for excepting `long long`?

Comment: So here is the update. From N4860 a draft that is close to C++20 - There are ﬁve standard signed integer types : “ signed char ”, “ short int ”, “ int ”, “ long int ”, and “ long long int ”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list.