# how is word size in computer related to int or long

Tags: c++, c, cpu-word, cpu-architecture

I have seen the link [What does it mean by word size in computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821103/what-does-it-mean-by-word-size-in-computer) . It defines what word size is. 
I am trying to represent very long string in bits where each character is represented by 4 bits and save it in long or integer array so that I can extract my string when required. 
I can save the bits either in integer array or long array.

> 1. If I use long array (8 bytes) I will be able to save 8*4=32 bits in one long array.
> 2. But if I use int I will be able to save 4*4=16 bits only.

Now, if I am given my Word Size=32 then is it the case that I should use int only and not long.

Comment: [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Comment: 4 bytes and 8 bytes respectively

Comment: Go read the above link, you are wrong, that is why I linked it.

Comment: Use the longest type you can - which is `long long`, not either of your options. The compiler and standard library are perfectly capable of handling this regardless of the local word size.

Comment: @CoryKramer I checked the sizeof(long) and sizeof(int) on my system which was 8 and 4 based on which I was working. But then this link clarifies something for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901080/why-is-the-sizeofint-sizeoflong

Comment: *"I checked the sizeof(long) and sizeof(int) **on my system**..."* that is the important part

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To answer your direct question: There is no guaranteed relationship between the natural word-size of the processor and the C and C++ types `int` or `long`. Yes, quite often `int` will be the same as the size of a register in the processor, but most 64-bit processors do not follow this rule, as it makes data unnecessarily large. On the other hand, an 8-bit processor would have a register size of 8 bits, but `int` according to the C and C++ standards needs to be at least 16 bits in size, so the compiler would have to use more than one register to represent one integer [in some fashion].

In general, if you want to KNOW how many bits or bytes some type is, it's best to NOT rely on `int`, `long`, `size_t` or `void *`, since they are all likely to be different for different processor architectures or even different compilers on the same architecture. An `int` or `long` may be the same size or different sizes. Only rule that the standard says is that `long` is at least 32 bits.

So, to have control of the number of bits, use `#include <cstdint>` (or in C, `stdint.h`), and use the types for example `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` - then you KNOW that it will hold a given number of bits.

On a processor that has 36-bit "wordsize", the type `uint32_t` for example, will not exist, since there is no type that holds exactly 32-bits [most likely]. Alternatively, the compiler may add extra instructions to "behave as if it's a 32-bit type" (in other words, sign extending if necessary, and masking off the top bits as needed)

Comment: humm is that true? i thought that on on a 36 bit "wordsize" they will just emulate a uint32_t with a 36 bit item and C/C++ will hide the extra space from you? I will see if I can find anything in standard about this though, I'm not sure

Comment: @Mats Petersson Isn't it fine that I check the sizeOf(long) and sizeOf(int) on my system and work based on its result

Comment: sizeof(sometype) * CHAR_BIT (from `<climits>`) will tell you how many bits. This is because `sizeof()` will give you the size in bytes, which is the size of `char`. So in the example of a 36-bit machine, a `char` would have `sizeof(char)==1`, but `CHAR_BIT == 9`, rather than the more common `CHAR_BIT==8` - of course, 36-bit machines are rather uncommon. But they do exist.

Comment: Sure you want to name the C++-only adaption of the standard C header, instead of the latter?

Comment: @ChrisBeck, no `uint32_t` and similar are, if they exist, guaranteed to have exactly the width, no padding. There might also be a type `uint_least32_t` that behaves similar to what you describe.

Comment: The first paragraph relieves my worry that I got a 32-bit CPU after seeing that `sizeof(int)` is 4 on my machine.