# Why do I get different result on Xcode (C Language)

Tags: printf, long-integer

```
long number = 100;
printf("the sizeof: %d", sizeof(number));
```

In Visual Studio, I get the result 4.
In Xcode, whereas I get the result 8.

Same code, different result. Could you tell me why I get this result?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901080/why-is-the-sizeofint-sizeoflong?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types): `long` is guaranteed by the standard to be "at least 32 bits", and depending on the data model may be bigger.

If you want "exactly 32 bits", try if [`int32_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is supported.